# Select statement returns no values when one table is empty

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables in MySQL:

```
BOOK(id int,isbn,title,publisher,author,...)
LEND(issueid,id int,enrno,dateofissue)
```

I want to display the rows from `BOOK` where

1. `Id` is not present in `LEND` (i.e is not already issued), and
2. Is like `'%s%'`

I want to use this query in my .NET C# application (datagridview)

I have written this query:

```
select * from book where id!=(select distinct id from lend) and title like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%';";
where textbox1.text is entered in textbox
```

This query shows no rows when `LEND` is empty. This is the problem, instead it should show all of the rows of `BOOK`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Change `!=` to `NOT IN`

Comment: WOW !!! that was Fast !!! Silly Mistake .. Thanks

Comment: You also don't need the DISTINCT in the subquery, if an item is removed once or 10 times makes no difference.

Answer (score 3):

The `!=` operator compares two scalar values. If you are looking for a way to check presence or absence of a particular value in a list, you can do one of the following:

#### Use `NOT IN`:

```
select *
from book where id NOT IN (
    select distinct id from lend
) and title like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%' -- <<== Parameterize this!
```

#### Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select *
from book where NOT EXISTS (
    select id from lend where lend.id = book.id
) and title like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%' -- <<== Parameterize this!
```

In both cases, you should replace user-entered data with a query parameter. It is extremely important, because otherwise your system would be open to SQL injection attacks. The exact syntax depends on the programming language inside which you host your query.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend a JOIN personally:

```
SELECT
    book.*
FROM
    book LEFT JOIN lend ON book.id = lend.id
WHERE
    lend.id IS NULL AND book.title LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'
```

Based on what I've read, this would be far more efficient that NOT IN because IN runs very slowly on indexes (I'm assuming that NOT IN is about the same, though I could be mistaken). "id" would be the PRIMARY KEY, which is an index.

Notably, though, if the tables are very small, then using NOT IN wouldn't make a huge difference. This type of efficiency is only a problem using very large tables, which I personally have had trouble in the past with before when using IN.

Comment: The query would use `NOT IN` which is very different (regarding execution and efficiency) to `IN`.

Comment: IN and NOT IN are based on the same thing. I just meant IN or NOT IN in general. NOT IN is just the opposite of IN. I'll update to clarify I meant NOT IN, though. I also added another note that the differences would be minimal if the database table is small.

Comment: You are wrong then. There are several preformance issues in mySQL with `IN (SELECT ...)` subqueries but there are no issues with `NOT IN (SELECT ...)`. The `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` solution you suggest would have similar execution plan to a `NOT IN` solution. See: [EXPLAIN EXTENDED](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) article.

Comment: There are some queries like this that definitely cannot work with a JOIN. This was a fairly simple NOT IN, though. Although, I did fail to correctly make sure that there weren't any extra special clauses in the query before I made my suggestion. I doubled-checked once I realized this just to confirm it was a simple query: (select distinct id from lend). A more advanced query would probably not (I won't say it "won't") be able to work the same way using a JOIN.

Comment: @ypercube, thanks for that article. I'm always looking for ways to improve query performance. I just bookmarked that website so I can look it up again later.